# Tailwind CSS does not work with the @apply rule in react/vite

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I initialized an app with react/vite, installed tailwind.css and tried to use the @apply in index.css. But the styles does not really apply, the div is with the class, but appear the error:
[Unknown property name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyAoD.png)
Here are my files:

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.container {
  @apply bg-red-500;
}
```

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

app.jsx

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I already tried to use jit in tailwind.config.js, but does not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Tailwind is missing from your CSS build pipeline. Consider checking you have `postcss` installed in your project. Then, check you have a `postcss.config.js` or `postcss.config.cjs` file in the root of your project, and it has `tailwindcss` as a `plugin` like:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
}
```

or

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: It worked, help me a lot thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem because I forgot to install `postcss` and `autoprefixer`.

`npm install -D postcss autoprefixer`

Then create a `postcss.config.js` file with the following content:

```
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```